# Output hidden input fields for each Variation of a Woocommerce variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hidden-field, product-variations

Having a problem in my store where I want to set up some hidden input fields. Each field relates to a variation ID of my product (they all have three variations)

```
<input type="hidden" class="one" name="id" value"value-of-first-variation"/>
<input type="hidden" class="two" name="id" value"value-of-second-variation"/>
<input type="hidden" class="three" name="id" value"value-of-three-variation"/>
```

But I'm very confused how to do this. I've seen a number of posts in SO about getting all the variation ID's but not sure how to do this final step and getting the value of each of these input field do a get operation to obtain the proper ID. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need this hidden fields as the variation ID appears already in a hidden field, when it's selected... You should clarify your question as we don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yea, it can get confusing. Basically I want to use all the variation ID’s in a series of Add to Cart URL’s using JS to add all the variations into the cart at once. I’ve got the product ID figured out. Just not this part.

Answer (score 0):

To get all Variation ID of any product, Try this -

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
        'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
        'order'         => 'asc',
        'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
    );
    $variations = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

        // get variation ID
        $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

        // get variations meta
        $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );

        // get variation featured image
        $variation_image = $product_variation->get_image();

        // get variation price
        $variation_price = $product_variation->get_price_html();


    }
```

OR

```
 $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

And if you want to add all the variation product into the cart, on single click (as per your comment), Then you can use jquery function where you first get all the variation id (Once page loaded), and then use ajax where you have to send all the input (variations ids) on another ajax page, and in the response you will get all the variation id in a link like -

`abc.com/?add-to-cart=121:1,538:1`

Here is the first parameter of variation id and second (after :) is quantity, You can add multiple variation ids separate with (,).

And then replace your add to cart button with the new link.

I know this is not the complete answer, but you will get some help from this.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried that Add to Cart link idea, which is where I was going with it as well, but using that ?add-to-cart=121"1,538:1 method didn't add anything to my WooCommerce based cart.

Comment: BTW, I tried the top method and it worked great. However, what if I just wanted to get one of my ID instead of all of them. Like let's say there are three ID's and I only wanted the second?

Comment: It should be like - abc.com/?add-to-cart=121:1,538:1 (not ?add-to-cart=121"1,538:1), Here in first parameter 121 is variation id with quantity 1, same for 538 (variation id) with quantity 1

Comment: So, do you want to get the selected variation Id or any specific id on page load?

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of the variations IDs in a Variable Product you will use [`WC_Product` `get_children()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html#_get_children).

In the below code you need to get the Variable product WC_Product object instance if you can get it using:

```
global $product;
```

In this case you will use:

```
// Get the Variable product WC_Product object instance
$product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
```

Now the rest of the code to display all needed hidden input fields related to the variation IDs:

```
$childern_variations_ids = $product->get_children(); // The variations IDs

// Loop through the array of Variations IDs to output related hidden fields
foreach(  $childern_variations_ids as $key => $variation_id ){
    // Output a hidden field for each variation ID
    echo '<input type="hidden" class="variation variation-'.$key.'" name="id" value"'.$variation_id.'"/>';
}
```

Now you get a set of hidden input fields related to the variation IDs for your variable products.